# How to set embedded SSRS report's results area to scroll horizontally if too wide

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I've created an SSRS report which contains a potentially very wide table of records. When I view this in the Report Builder application (Fig. 1) or in my browser from the SSRS portal (Fig. 2), it correctly displays the parameters pane at the top at 100% width of the display area and displays a horizontal scrollbar on the results area so that I can scroll right to see all of the table's columns.

However, when I embed the report in my MVC web application, which is the main purpose of the report, the horizontal scrollbar is not displayed, meaning that the right-most columns are always hidden (Fig. 3). As you can see in the screenshot, it isn't a case of setting the `overflow` style property on the container on the web page because the content isn't overflowing - the parameters pane perfectly uses the width available. I've tried all sorts of `overflow` settings and nothing changes.

The best I've been able to achieve is to set the width of the `iframe` displaying the embedded report to be > 100%. This causes it to overflow in its parent `div`, to which I can apply `overflow: auto` to get a scrollbar (Fig. 4). the problem with that is the parameters pane still fills the width of the `iframe` into which it's loaded, so the "View Report" button is always off screen and the user has to scroll right every single time just to run the report, which is probably the worst experience of all.

Does anybody know why the report doesn't show a horizontal scrollbar on the embedded report area like it does when viewed natively in SSRS? And is there a way to fix it? I've played with the Interactive Page width and the Page width and a myriad of other things but nothing works.

[image: Report viewed in Report Bulider]
Fig. 1

[image: Report viewed in SSRS reports portal]
Fig. 2

[image: Report embedded in web page]
Fig. 3

[image: Reported embedded in web page with parent iframe set to 150% width]
Fig. 4